# Replace a specific column of a specific row with awk

Tags: awk

i am using the following code to replace column 8 of row 10 with the sum of column 8 divided by 10, which should give me an average of that column. I then want to print the final row. It hasnt worked so far.

```
awk -F "|"  '{sum+= $8} FNR==10{$8=$sum/10}'
```

I would appreciate any help, thank you

Comment: When you say average, do you mean, average of all rows, or just the rows till that row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a *bug*, should be:

```
awk -F "|"  '{sum+= $8} FNR==10{$8=sum/10}'
```